# DataGridView Column binding in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to design a `DataGrid` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I am planning to bind the `DataGrid` to list of objects of a class. The class I was planning is

```
class Class1
{
    public Int32 Index { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Srno { get; set; }
}
```

I have a problem. I would like to have one more colour property which I can bind directly to the colour of the `DataGrid` in column2. But since I am planning to set `DataGrid` binding to list of this object, the new property will be recognized as a column itself. How do I avoid that? Any suggetions.

Comment: Set AutoGenerateColumns equals to false in Grid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `False` and take responsibility in your hand to provide the list of columns you want to avoid auto generation of columns when DataSource or DataMember properties are set.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Index}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Colour}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Srno}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<DataGrid  Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" Binding="{Binding Path=Index}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Colour" Binding="{Binding Path=Colour}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Path=Location}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Srno" Binding="{Binding Path=Srno}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

This is how you would do it, if you set the Datagrid1.ItemsSource = a List of Class1, like so.

```
 List<Class1> myList = new List<Class1>();
 DataGrid1.ItemsSource = myList;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You want to replace the Colour property value to another Colour Property value it can be done using rowdatabound.

AS you set Autogenerate Columns = "false"

Columns : Index , Colour , Location and SrNo will display in Datagrid

you are saying you have another colour who's value should replace COLOUR Column in the datagrid.If I am correct you can do this by the following...

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Index}"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Colour" SortExpression="Colour">
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
            <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblColor" Text='<%# Bind("Colour") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Srno}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

VB.net :

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView.RowDataBound
            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Or e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 
            End If

            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim lblColor1 As Label

                lblColor1 = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblColor"), Label)

                 lblColor1.Text = dtData.Rows(e.row.rowindex).ItemArray(0).tostring() ' 
' ItemArray Defined the Column Position. here give your Another Colour Column Value
            End If

        End Sub
```

c#.net :

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header | e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        Label lblColor1 = default(Label);

        lblColor1 = e.Row.FindControl("lblColor") as Label;

        lblColor1.Text = dtData.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex).ItemArray(0).tostring();
        // 
        // ItemArray Defined the Column Position. here give your Another Colour Column Value
    }

}
```